# Conditional multplication in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am building a forecast sheet for a new project and I am stuck on how to conditional multiplication in excel.

what I am trying to achieve is:

A1 = 10 | A2 = 10 | A3 = 5

A1 * A2 (until a total of 1000) then change to A1 * A3

It needs to use A2 up to the 1000 mark then from 1000 on use A3 so I can use the standard if If >1000 then use A3 formula.

this is an electricity forecast as I have a set rate (A2) till '1000' units is consumed then I am given rate (A3) and I wanted to know if this can be automated so I can create different models without needing to manually rework it every time?

Thanks and I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Hi, is: "IF(ROW()<1000;$A$1*$A$2;$A$1*$A$3)" what you're looking for?

Comment: Will this A2 up to the 1000 mark and then from the 1000 mark on use A3 or will this just mean if it exceeds A2 then it will only use A3?

I need it to use A2 up to the 1000 mark and then A3 from 1000 onwards, sorry iI don't think i had that in my main post i will update it now.

Comment: What do you mean with "up to the 1000 mark"? Do you have data all the way down in column A? Or does the data in A1 and A2 change? The data architecture is not clear. Edit your question. Post a screenshot and explain the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to calculate in a single column format. The below image is how I would approach this problem.

Range `D10:E21` contains the formula `=MIN(D$8-SUM(D$9:D9),$B10-SUM($C10:C10))`
Range `D23:E23` contains the formula `=D7*SUM(D10:D22)`

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect especially when I was struggling to explain what I meant!